# How to avoid zombie process from crond ( crond -l 9 )

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

1. My system based on Linux ( 3.12.14 ), I could see Zombie process [ sh ] 
   creates for very frequently.
2. I have found that (crond -l 9) which was parent process of zombie. I confirmed that, always crond -l 9 was parent process.
3. As per crontab (crontab  -l), lot of scripts are running based on configuration.
4. Do we have any solution for this issue? Or How can we avoid zombie process without restarting crond process?
5. We do not have options to restart crond since lot of real time specific scripts are running as part of crondtab configuration.
6. It's clearly shows 'sh' becomes zombie ([sh] and its parent process is crond ( crond -l 9 ) running.

Comment: That's not cron creating the zombies. The scripts are. They are not waiting for the children they create.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to this way.

```sh
sudo su

crontab -e

* * * * * pkill cron
```